# Ampscript duplicating first section box multiple times

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Hi I have some ampscript that pulls data in from the data extension into the email template. When I preview it the first section shows up 3 times as a duplicate but the other two sections show fine. I'm trying to stop the first section from showing up 3 times. I checked for similar questions but not having much luck. Maybe I need a second pair of eyes to see what I missed.

```
%%[

set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("Consult_Notifications_Daily_Digest",3,"date desc","EmailAddress",emailaddr)

]%%

%%[

set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowcount > 1 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    set @row = row(@rows,@i)
    set @mentionNotificationType = field(@row,"NotificationType_Mention_1")
    set @mentionNotificationType = field(@row,"NotificationType_Mention_2")
    set @mentionNotificationType = field(@row,"NotificationType_Mention_3")

    set @mentionPostName = field(@row,"PostName_4")
    set @mentionPostName5 = field(@row,"PostName_5")
    set @mentionPostName6 = field(@row,"PostName_6")

    set @mentionTargetURL = field(@row,"targeturl_4")
    set @mentionTargetURL5 = field(@row,"targeturl_5")
    set @mentionTargetURL6 = field(@row,"targeturl_6")

    set @mentionRecipientName = field(@row,"RecipientName")
    set @mentionMentionedUser = field(@row,"MENTIONEDUSER")
    set @mentionActorName = field(@row,"ActorNameDeg")
    set @mentionUser = field(@row,"User_1")
    set @mentionPostTitle = field(@row,"PostTitle_4")
    set @mentionUserAccountUrl = field(@row,"UserAccountUrl")

    set @mentionActorAccountUrl = field(@row,"ActorAccountUrl_4")
    set @mentionActorAccountUrl5 = field(@row,"ActorAccountUrl_5")
    set @mentionActorAccountUrl6 = field(@row,"ActorAccountUrl_6")

    set @mentionThreadUrl = field(@row,"ThreadUrl_4")
    set @mentionThreadUrl5 = field(@row,"ThreadUrl_5")
    set @mentionThreadUrl6 = field(@row,"ThreadUrl_6")

    set @mentionDate = field(@row,"Date")

    set @mentionPostBody = field(@row,"PostBody_4")
    set @mentionPostBody5 = field(@row,"PostBody_5")
    set @mentionPostBody6 = field(@row,"PostBody_6")

      if @mentionNotificationType == 'User' then

]%%
-->

        <tr>
          <td style="padding: 7px 0 0 0;">
            <table width="560" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" borde="0" class="container">
              <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding:2px 2px 3px 1px; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);" bgcolor="#dfdfdf">
                  <table width="558" class="container" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <tr>
                      <td style="padding:20px 20px 20px 20px; font-size: 14px;" align="left">
                        <table width="508" class="container" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                          <tr>
                            <td width="508" style="padding: 0 0px 0 0;" class="container" colspan="1" valign="top">
                              <table width="508" class="container" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="left" style="font-size: 18px;font-family: 'Roboto Condensed','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: none; padding:0 0 10px 0; line-height: normal;">
                                    <a href="%%=redirectTo(@mentionTargetURL)=%%" style="font-size: 18px;color: #000000;text-decoration:none;font-family: 'Roboto Condensed','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: none; padding:0 0 10px 0; line-height: normal;">%%=v(@mentionPostName)=%%</a>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                %%[if not empty(@mentionPostBody) then]%%
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="left" style="font-size: 14px;font-family: 'Roboto Condensed','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: none; padding:0 0 10px 0; line-height: normal; color: #606060;">
                                    %%=v(@mentionPostBody)=%% .. <a href="%%=redirectTo(@followedReplyTargetURL)=%%" target="_blank" style="font-size: 14px;font-family: 'Proxima Nova','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; color: #007cb0;">read more</a>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                %%[endif]%%
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="left" style="padding: 0px 0 0px 0; font-size: 14px;font-family: 'Proxima Nova','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; color: #3a3b3c;">
                                    <a href="%%=redirectTo(@mentionActorAccountUrl)=%%" target="_blank" style="font-size: 14px;font-family: 'Proxima Nova','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; color: #007cb0;">%%=v(@mentionRecipientName)=%%</a> responded to your post on %%=v(@mentionDate)=%%.
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
 <!-- End script
%%[

else

endif next @i endif

]%%
-->


        <tr>
          <td style="padding: 7px 0 0 0;">
            <table width="560" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" borde="0" class="container">
              <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding:2px 2px 3px 1px; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);" bgcolor="#dfdfdf">
                  <table width="558" class="container" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <tr>
                      <td style="padding:20px 20px 20px 20px; font-size: 14px;" align="left">
                        <table width="508" class="container" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                          <tr>
                            <td width="508" style="padding: 0 0px 0 0;" class="container" colspan="1" valign="top">
                              <table width="508" class="container" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="left" style="font-size: 18px;font-family: 'Roboto Condensed','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: none; padding:0 0 10px 0; line-height: normal;">
                                    <a href="%%=redirectTo(@mentionTargetURL5)=%%" style="font-size: 18px;color: #000000;text-decoration:none;font-family: 'Roboto Condensed','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: none; padding:0 0 10px 0; line-height: normal;">%%=v(@mentionPostName5)=%%</a>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                %%[if not empty(@mentionPostBody5) then]%%
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="left" style="font-size: 14px;font-family: 'Roboto Condensed','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: none; padding:0 0 10px 0; line-height: normal; color: #606060;">
                                    %%=v(@mentionPostBody5)=%% .. <a href="%%=redirectTo(@followedReplyTargetUR5L)=%%" target="_blank" style="font-size: 14px;font-family: 'Proxima Nova','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; color: #007cb0;">read more</a>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                %%[endif]%%
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="left" style="padding: 0px 0 0px 0; font-size: 14px;font-family: 'Proxima Nova','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; color: #3a3b3c;">
                                    <a href="%%=redirectTo(@mentionActorAccountUrl5)=%%" target="_blank" style="font-size: 14px;font-family: 'Proxima Nova','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; color: #007cb0;">%%=v(@mentionRecipientName)=%%</a> responded to your post on %%=v(@mentionDate)=%%.
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
 <!-- End script
%%[

else

endif next @i endif

]%%
-->


        <tr>
          <td style="padding: 7px 0 0 0;">
            <table width="560" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" borde="0" class="container">
              <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding:2px 2px 3px 1px; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);" bgcolor="#dfdfdf">
                  <table width="558" class="container" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <tr>
                      <td style="padding:20px 20px 20px 20px; font-size: 14px;" align="left">
                        <table width="508" class="container" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                          <tr>
                            <td width="508" style="padding: 0 0px 0 0;" class="container" colspan="1" valign="top">
                              <table width="508" class="container" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="left" style="font-size: 18px;font-family: 'Roboto Condensed','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: none; padding:0 0 10px 0; line-height: normal;">
                                    <a href="%%=redirectTo(@mentionTargetURL6)=%%" style="font-size: 18px;color: #000000;text-decoration:none;font-family: 'Roboto Condensed','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: none; padding:0 0 10px 0; line-height: normal;">%%=v(@mentionPostName6)=%%</a>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                %%[if not empty(@mentionPostBody6) then]%%
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="left" style="font-size: 14px;font-family: 'Roboto Condensed','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: none; padding:0 0 10px 0; line-height: normal; color: #606060;">
                                    %%=v(@mentionPostBody6)=%% .. <a href="%%=redirectTo(@followedReplyTargetURL6)=%%" target="_blank" style="font-size: 14px;font-family: 'Proxima Nova','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; color: #007cb0;">read more</a>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                %%[endif]%%
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="left" style="padding: 0px 0 0px 0; font-size: 14px;font-family: 'Proxima Nova','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; color: #3a3b3c;">
                                    <a href="%%=redirectTo(@mentionActorAccountUrl6)=%%" target="_blank" style="font-size: 14px;font-family: 'Proxima Nova','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; color: #007cb0;">%%=v(@mentionRecipientName)=%%</a> responded to your post on %%=v(@mentionDate)=%%.
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
 <!-- End script
        <!--End Content -->
        <tr>
          <td align="center" class="mobile-pad-top-20" style="padding: 22px 0 0 0; font-size: 16px;font-family: 'Proxima Nova','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: none; color: #3a3b3c; line-height: normal;">
            <a href="%%=redirectTo(@mentionUserAccountUrl)=%%" target="_blank" style="font-size: 16px;font-family: 'Proxima Nova','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; color: #007cb0;">
            See all your posts
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- -->
<!-- -->
<!--END -->
```

Comment: Your `LookupOrderedRows` is set to return 3 rows and if the result returns 3 successful rows then it will loop through 3 times displaying 3 results. I haven't tested your code but visually, this seems to be the case as to why you may be experiencing duplicate sections.

Comment: You have the wrong idea how that loop behaves like thechrishaddad already said. You will start rowtimes in that whole stuff. With your next @i you jump at the beginning to the loop. What you want is something like `for @i = 1 to @rowCount do IF @i==1 Then ...  elseif @i==2 then ... elseif @i==3 then ... else ... endif next @i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd recommend *not* hiding your AMPscript code with HTML comments. That seems to be part of the issue.  There are several `<!--` opens without `-->` closes and vice versa.

As it's written, you're going to get the same thing each time since you're overwriting your primary conditional variable values.

```
set @mentionNotificationType = field(@row,"NotificationType_Mention_1")
set @mentionNotificationType = field(@row,"NotificationType_Mention_2")
set @mentionNotificationType = field(@row,"NotificationType_Mention_3")
```

Not sure why you have multiple `endif next @i endif` clauses.

As [@Johannes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/52639/johannes-schapdick) pointed out, you're looping through the result-set but you have code for each of the three cases.  I'd recommend adding conditionals for each of the three rows in the resultset as he suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Just to include it as answer.
You have the wrong idea how that loop behaves like thechrishaddad already said and some of your code does not make sense like @[Adam Spriggs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/5202/adam-spriggs) said.

What you would like to have is something like this:

```
for @i = 1 to @rowCount do 
    if @i==1 then
        /* Do Stuff */ 
    elseif @i==2 then 
        /* Do Stuff */  
    elseif @i==3 then
        /* Do Stuff */ 
    else
        /* Do Stuff */ 
    endif 
next @i
```

Some explanations why your code does not work:

```
for @i = 1 to @rowCount do 
    /* Do Stuff */
next @i

/* The following code (next i) would never be executed, because the next i call jumps to the beginning of the for loop*/
/* and would probably be even marked as error or warning*/
next @i
```

Resources:

- [**AmpScript documentation that uses a for loop**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/AMPscript401.htm)
- [**Process Loops from Eliot and Adam on ampscript.guide**](https://ampscript.guide/process-loops/)